# Erro Java - Scheduled

Tags: java

Estou me deparando com o seguinte erro ao tentar compilar o código da imagem.
Criei um projeto apenas para testar o código, e aparece isso.
Não encontrei erro similar em outros lugares, alguém pode me ajudar?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
package testet;    
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Component    
@EnableScheduling    
public class TesteT {            
  private final long SEGUNDO = 1000;    
  private final long MINUTO = SEGUNDO * 60;    
  private final long HORA = MINUTO * 60;

  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 * * *")    
  public void verificaPorHora() {    
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
    // Código que realiza a consulta de fluxo de vendas
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: Bem vinda ao stackoverflow. Edite a pergunta e adicione em forma textual, tanto seu código quanto o erro, assim facilita te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

O erro refere-se a anotação `@Component`, que não foi importada na sua classe `TestT`.

Para corrigir, use:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
```

Creio que terá o mesmo problema com `@EnableScheduling`

Comment: Obrigado Dherik, mas não consigo importar. Sabe se funciona para desktop e onde eu encontro? Sou iniciante em java.

Comment: @CamilaC.Piva, você precisa importar as dependências do Spring para seu projeto. Como está começando, sugiro dar uma olhada no Spring Initializr: https://start.spring.io. Ele vai te ajudar com as dependências e já dispõe de uma base de artefatos do Spring pronto para usar, sem muita configuração.

Comment: É só gerar e importar ele nas bibliotecas?
@Dherik

Comment: Creio que sim. Pode ser que alguma dependência mais específica não esteja no projeto, mas você pode vir depois aqui no SOpt, fazer uma nova pergunta e esperar que alguém a ajude a solucionar. Ou, se quiser, pode procurar de qual pacote do Spring esta dependência vem e gerar novamente o pacote OU adicionar a dependência você mesma no arquivo pom.xml.